# Mascara de moedas no campo

Tags: android

Gostaria de criar mascaras no meu campo tipo numero do android.
Já consegui adicionar a mascara ###,##.
Mas isto não é uma boa prática, pois caso eu queira adicionar um valor de R$ 1.000,00 o campo não aceita.
Alguém ai já passou por isso ou parecido ?

Answer (score 8):

Artur, eu tenho uma classe `TextWatcher`que utilizo no meu projeto, veja se serve pra você:

```
public class MoneyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private final WeakReference<EditText> editTextWeakReference;
    private final Locale locale;

    public MoneyTextWatcher(EditText editText, Locale locale) {
        this.editTextWeakReference = new WeakReference<EditText>(editText);
        this.locale = locale != null ? locale : Locale.getDefault();
    }

    public MoneyTextWatcher(EditText editText) {
        this.editTextWeakReference = new WeakReference<EditText>(editText);
        this.locale = Locale.getDefault();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        EditText editText = editTextWeakReference.get();
        if (editText == null) return;
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        BigDecimal parsed = parseToBigDecimal(editable.toString(), locale);
        String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format(parsed);

        editText.setText(formatted);
        editText.setSelection(formatted.length());
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    private BigDecimal parseToBigDecimal(String value, Locale locale) {
        String replaceable = String.format("[%s,.\\s]", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).getCurrency().getSymbol());

        String cleanString = value.replaceAll(replaceable, "");

        return new BigDecimal(cleanString).setScale(
            2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).divide(new BigDecimal(100), BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR
        );
    }
}
```

No seu `EditText` adicione o `TextWatcher`:

```
Locale mLocale = new Locale("pt", "BR");
mEditTextValorParc.addTextChangedListener(new MoneyTextWatcher(mEditTextValorParc, mLocale));
```

Neste caso, ela vai formatando o `EditText` conforme o usuário vai digitando os números, como acontece em uma máquina de cartão de crédito. Se ele digitar por exemplo o número 2, ficaria **0,02**, se logo após ele digitar o 1, ficaria **0,21**, e assim por diante.

Comment: Deu certo aqui. Com ajuda de outro cara consegui implementar. Obrigado

Comment: Excelente! Obrigado

Comment: A solução até é interessante. O problema é quando o símbolo monetário vem depois do número. Tentar apagar dá erro e não é simples de corrigir.